# SSRS Report builder 3 - Hide Row based on value using expresion

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to SSRS and I want to hide rows based on value. My report has 3 columns Date||Employee||Location.
Location field is getting populated from another data set based on employee. I have used IIF and Lookup expression

```
(IIF(Fields!loc.Value=lookup(Fields!emp.Value,Fields!emp.Value,Fields!loc.Value,
"Dateset1_Test"),Fields!loc.Value,"NULL")
```

.
Now in my final result I wanted to hide rows which are have NULL value in location column, to do that I am using Row Visibility option and using below expression to hide the row but it does not work, either it shows all the rows or hides all the rows -

```
`> IIF(Fields!loc.Value=lookup(Fields!loc.Value,Fields!loc.Value,Fields!loc.Value,  "LocTrace_Test"),Fields!loc.Value,"NULL")



> IIF(Fields!loc.Value=lookup(Fields!loc.Value,Fields!loc.Value,Fields!loc.Value,
 "LocTrace_Test"),Fields!loc.Value,"NULL")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7LV0.png)

Comment: You can add your image inline, please follow instructions here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344853/3519504

Comment: You need to use isnothing for NULL.  = "NULL" means equals the string value of NULL.. which is not the same as nothing

Comment: Ok. I used data filter to get the desired result. Thanks for support.